# rigify shoulder is creating a really bad crease

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, rigify

[image: Shoulder 3]
[image: Shoulder 2]
[image: Shoulder]
The shoulder part creates a crease, the collarbone doesnt affect the mesh at all. I watches some tutorials that have reactive shoulders, my rigify one doesnt move at all.

Comment: First of all, the way the arm will bend will depend on the position of the bone head, so it's strange that the head is located here

Comment: WHere should it be placed?

Comment: The bone head should be placed where you want your arm to bend, at its center of rotation

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the shoulder bones and add the Rig type `basic.super.copy` and then change the widget to *Shoulder*.

You can check the armature of the metarig that they give you as an example, there it is already fully configured, if you have doubts check it, I figured it out that way.